# How to automate upgrade yarn for private packages?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to automate yarn package which is private npm package published on github. I tried making `.yarnrc.yml` file which looks like this

```
npmScopes:
  yarn-package-publisher:
    npmPublishRegistry: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com/'
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: my_token
```

and i ran `yarn config set .yarnrc.yml` and tried to upgrade through `yarn upgrade` the other solution I tried is  making `.yarnrc` which looks like this

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=my_token
@neetesshhr:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
always-auth=true
```

and ran the above command but got permission issue. 
**Note** I am trying to automate to upgrade my packages through jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I got my node version was 18x so I have to use node 14.x and use .npmrc file and set the yarn config to install my creds to node modules and I deployed it now working as I expected to be.
`yarn config set .npmrc`